# Public ip address showing in Hong Kong

Tags: networking, dns, ip

It seems that my range of ip address are all showing as if they are in HK. For example, when I use google search, I am stuck on the .hk search site and it is extremely annoying.

I also host a email server and I'm getting return blocked emails due to locaion.

I did a traceroute on the site via this site:

http://www.whatsmyip.org/traceroute/

and it returned back this result:

[image]

The last ip address it not mine. My server is located in the Dallas data center.

When I try to pinpoint my location on Google search or maps, it shows I'm in HK.

I inquired with my hosting provider for my dedicated server and this was their response:

There is no way for us to control ip geolocation. Most services use the rwhois data and show the correct location. Google however uses some other method that is often incorrect. The best thing you can do is to login to your google account and it should then show the correct location.

This is not specific to google. I used them as an example.

This is happening on my range of ip addresses so it is not specific to my virtual machine, it's happening on all of them. This is why I thought it was a host issue.

This is annoying and it is slowing down my research. Anyone have any suggestions? What else is needed to determine my issue? I'll be happy to get it right away.

Answer (score 0):

Whatismyip.com can report your location. What is it?
http://www.whatsmyip.org/ip-geo-location/

What is your browser language setting?

An IP-range might be sold to another company. If at first that range was located in HK, and now elsewhere, it will take some time to get location databases up to date I guess.

Comment: Ironically, it shows at my home town, which is several states away. Not sure why that is the case. The language settings are set to English (United States).  Thanks for the input. I guess I'll just wait :(

Comment: Contact Google about this. They will reply to such a report and probably fix it, if the problem is on their side, which is likely.